# MongoDB -How to get last 30 days date from given date and that last 30 days date should be current date?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am the beginner of MongoDB

Here I mentioned below my one document

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e5bc292361b710c7727718e"),
"branch_id" : "BR5cc825dac42dac3aae49ff91",
"inventory" : [ 
    {
        "inventory_stock_id" : "wewe123",
        "stock_name" : "xxxxx",
        "stock_point" : "27",
        "stock_type" : "yyyy",
        "batch" : [ 
            {
                "quantity" : 40,
                "manf_date" : "10-01-2020",
                "exp_date" : "01-04-2020"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I want to get last 30 days from **"exp_date"** but it should be **equal** to **current date**

Here I mentioned **exp_date: "01-04-2020"** and the past 30 days of date is today date( **"02-03-2020"**)

```
db.collection.find({"inventory.batch.exp_date" : {"$lte":"01-04-2020","$eq":"02-03-2020"}})
```

I don't know how to get last 30 days of **exp_date** and equal to current date

so anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Why do you want to use lte and eq both? Wouldn't equal to today date suffice?

Comment: @Jaiprakash Actually I want to get last 30 days of expiry date but last day of 30 should be equal to today date.

Comment: Something like this: `exp_date - 30 days == today's date`

Comment: You compare strings, that's bad. "01-04-2020" is lower than "02-03-2020" because "01" is lower than "02". Store date values properly as `Date` objects.

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Do you like to get records where `exp_date` is the current date or "> today - 30 days"? Both at the same time is not possible.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit My requirement is last 30 days of exp_date but 30 th day is equal to todays date similar like this : exp_date - 30 days == today's date

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is a bad approach to store/compare `Date` values as strings.

You can do it like this. First convert the strings to proper `Date` objects:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
   {},
   [
      {
         $set: {
            inventory: {
               $map: {
                  input: "$inventory",
                  as: "inventory",
                  in: {
                     $mergeObjects: [
                        "$$inventory",
                        {
                           batch: {
                              $map: {
                                 input: "$$inventory.batch",
                                 in: {
                                    quantity: "$$this.quantity",
                                    manf_date: { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$$this.manf_date", format: "%d-%m-%Y" } },
                                    exp_date: { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$$this.exp_date", format: "%d-%m-%Y" } }
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
)
```

When you have to work with Date values, then I recommend the [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library. 
The query would be this one:

```
db.collection.find(
   {
      "inventory.batch": {
         $elemMatch: {
            exp_date: {
               $eq: moment().utc().add(30, 'days').startOf('day').toDate()
            }
         }
      }
   }
)
```

or as aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $match: {
         "inventory.batch": {
            $elemMatch: {
               exp_date: {
                  $eq: moment().utc().add(30, 'days').startOf('day').toDate()
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Note, by default `$dateFromString` uses **UTC** times, whereas `moment()` uses your local time by default. Thus you have to use either `moment().utc()` or you specify the `timezone` field at `$dateFromString`.

In case you insist to keep the string values as Date, you can also use

```
db.collection.find(
   {
      "inventory.batch": {
         $elemMatch: {
            exp_date: {
               $eq: moment().add(30, 'days').startOf('day').format("DD-MM-YYYY")
            }
         }
      }
   }
)
```

However, this will fail if you query with `$gte, $ge, $lt, $lte` operators.

**Update**

If you have not access to `moments` then you can run in purely in the aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $unwind: "$inventory" },
   { $set: { ts: { $dateToParts: { date: { $add: ["$$NOW", { $multiply: [1000, 60, 60, 24, 30] }] } } } } },
   {
      $set: {
         ts: {
            $dateFromParts: {
               year: "$ts.year",
               month: "$ts.month",
               day: "$ts.day",
               timezone: "UTC"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $set: { matches: { $in: ["$ts", "$inventory.batch.exp_date"] } } },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: { _id: "$_id", branch_id: "$branch_id" },
         inventory: { $push: "$$ROOT.inventory" },
         matches: { $push: "$$ROOT.matches" }
      }
   },
   { $match: { $expr: { $anyElementTrue: "$matches" } } },
   { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: ["$$ROOT", "$_id"] } } },
   {$unset: "matches"}
])
```

Or, if you like to write all on a single aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $unwind: "$inventory" },
   {
      $set: {
         "inventory.batch": {
            $map: {
               input: "$inventory.batch",
               in: {
                  quantity: "$$this.quantity",
                  manf_date: { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$$this.manf_date", format: "%d-%m-%Y" } },
                  exp_date: { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$$this.exp_date", format: "%d-%m-%Y" } }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $set: { ts: { $dateToParts: { date: { $add: ["$$NOW", { $multiply: [1000, 60, 60, 24, 30] }] } } } } },
   {
      $set: {
         ts: {
            $dateFromParts: {
               year: "$ts.year",
               month: "$ts.month",
               day: "$ts.day",
               timezone: "UTC"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $set: { matches: { $in: ["$ts", "$inventory.batch.exp_date"] } } },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: { _id: "$_id", branch_id: "$branch_id" },
         inventory: { $push: "$$ROOT.inventory" },
         matches: { $push: "$$ROOT.matches" }
      }
   },
   { $match: { $expr: { $anyElementTrue: "$matches" } } },
   { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: ["$$ROOT", "$_id"] } } },
   { $unset: "matches" }
])
```

Comment: Here moment() used but I used backend python so how can I use moment?

Comment: I assume python has also some build-in function to manipulate Date values.

Comment: So please give an alternate solution